# errorX3013: vertex shader does not take 0 arguments

Tags: xna, hlsl

I am starting to play around with the Shader Model 4.0 and I'm trying to setup a basic sample project. (Basically rendering and light up a cube)

But atm. I am totally stuck at the most basic part. My Vertex Shader won't compile with the following error message:

Error   1   Errors compiling ...\x.fx:

...\x.fx(32,43): **error X3013: 'VertexShaderFunction': function does not take 0 parameters**   ...\x.fx    32  43  ...

my code until now:

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
};

VS_OUTPUT VertexShaderFunction(in VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    return output;
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        SetVertexShader( Compile( vs_4_1, VertexShaderFunction() ) );
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
        SetPixelShader( NULL );
    }
}
```

the VS_INPUT parameter is clearly marked as input and not as uniform. The struct assigns every member (well the only one) an input semantic. Does anyone have an idea why this is not compiling properly?

I am using **Win7 Ultimate + DirectX11 + XNA GameStudio 4.0**,
my graphics card is an **Intel GMA 4500MHD** (so it should allow for shader model 4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and her I go, answering my own question - what a stupid mistake (and hard to find):

it is CompileShader() and not Compile()